# open Facebook page from the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I was trying to open the Facebook app with particular Facebook page from my app with the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/pagename"];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

When I click on the button it opens the Facebook app but the required page doesn't load or show.

Is there any other way to open the Facebook app with particular Facebook page? Please correct me If I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well you are using `http` instead of `https` and if that's not the problem try loading the page by id `https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_ID"`

Comment: @FabioAntunes Ok buddy I will try as you suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the facebook app directly you should do the following:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://profile/PAGE_ID"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://profile/PAGE_ID"]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://facebook.com/PAGE_NAME"]];
}
```

This is a solution including a fallback for web.

To determine your PAGE_ID you could use a service like [this](http://findmyfacebookid.com).